# Global first integral for certain $3$ dimensional system

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

A physicist colleague asks me the following question. I have no idea to answer him. Your answer is very appreciated.

Is there a global first integral on $\mathbb{R}^3$ for the following vector field?

$$\begin{cases}x'=sin(y) \\
y'=sin(z)\\
z'=sin(x)
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Is this to be read as $x$, $y$, $z$ depending on one parameter, say, "$t$" and the prime denotes the derivative w.r.t. $t$? And what is sought is the solution of this set of first-order differential equations?

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt yes $x'=dx/dt$.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt  by the second part of your comment do you mean "what is the motivation for consideration of this system"? I have no idea of such a motovation. I can ask him.

Comment: No no, the second part of my comment was simply to make sure I understood what form of answer was expected - I suppose that was a bit redundant once the first part was clarified. The second part was simply reinforcing the first part. Still, it would be interesting where this arises - but don't go to any length investigating, it's not essential of course.

Comment: Now, for small $x$, $y$, $z$, the solutions of course are of the form $x=\exp (t)$, $\exp (\exp (i 2\pi /3) t)$ or $\exp (\exp (i 4\pi /3) t)$, with $y$, $z$ obtained by differentiation, but this is probably obvious to your colleague, since he explicitly asks for a global answer ...

Answer (score 3):

One can find a solution of the form $x=y=z$, namely, $x=2$arccot$(\exp (-t-a))$ with the free parameter $a$. Of course, there should be more. Note also the symmetries of the problem: For any solution $(x,y,z)$, also $(-x,-y,-z)$ is a solution, as is $(x+2k\pi,y+2l\pi,z+2m\pi)$, with arbitrary integers $k,l,m$.

Comment: The latter symmetries presumably provide useful guardrails if one ultimately wants to resort to a numerical solution - one only has to interpolate between two adjacent analytic solutions bounding the direction of the vector $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: In particular, for large $x$, $y$, $z$, one is always very close to one of the analytic solutions. In combination with the form of solutions for small  $x$, $y$, $z$ in comments above, there isn't that much wiggle room left.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I  will forward your answer to him. by global first integral I mean a function $f:\mathbb{R}63 \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f_x sin(y)+f_y sin(z)+f_z sin(x0=0$. may be your answer can help to find this globaly defined first integral. Thanks again for consideration of the question.

Comment: Oh - looks like we talked past each other then ... this is what I was trying to clarify with my initial question, but it seems we still didn't quite match minds. Still, maybe this helps anyway. I'll update if I think of anything else.

Comment: Indeed, the trajectories $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ I describe are by construction equipotential lines, i.e., lines of constant $f$, to the extent that $f$ exists. So they at least provide a scaffolding for a more complete construction of $f$.